# Cuckoo permission denied for .vmx file on a Mac OS Host

Tags: vmware, sandbox, macos-sierra, malware, malware-detection

I am facing an issue when I try to run the cuckoo sandbox after all the installation.

Host Machine: macOS machine with VMware Fusion running. Guest : Windows VM

I installed the Cuckoo Sandbox in a virtual environment within macOS. I did edit the vmware.conf, memorey.conf, cuckoo.conf & processing.conf files.

When i do run the "cuckoo" command to start; it says it doesnt have permisssion to access the .vmx file I mentioned in the "vmware.conf" file.

I have given 777 permission to the entire folder. Not sure why the system gives me such an error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a user in the system for the cuckoo sandbox, kindly assign appropriate privileges to the cuckoo sandbox user.